# Altering styling based on row order of ampscript loops

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a table of the top 3 food brands available at each location.

I.e.

```
Location | Brand      
-----------------------
New York | Coffee Shop
New York | Bagel Shop
New York | Deli 
Houston  | Steakhouse
Houston  | Bagel Shop
Houston  | Smoothies
```

I generated a rowset of available Brands at a specific Location (matching that of the current user viewing the content).

I.e.

Joe is viewing the email and he is located in Houston.
I want him to see the top 3 food shops in Houston.
I've been able to get this to display with a loop, however, what I have been stumped on is the styling piece.

The tricky part is each block he sees will have an image icon detonating the rank of that shop. 
Since I know it will always be 3 brands displayed, is there a way I can call out for "Row 1" use image icon number 1, for "Row 2", use image icon number 2, for "Row 3", use image icon number 3.

[image]

After each brand is listed there is also a different Call to Action link and a separator, but by the third brand, I do not want there to be a separator under it.

I've only been able to create a loop that displays the different brands and images, but I can't figure out how to change the number icon according to it's rank, and I can't figure out how to change the CTAs according to it's rank either.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far -- like the some abbreviated code?

Comment: Without any of your code, this looks like a test question.  Hope that's not the case.

Answer (score 4):

You can just output the separator as long as you're not on the final product in your loop:

```
%%[

var @i, @max
set @max = 3

]%%

%%[ for @i = 1 to @max do ]%%

    %%[ if @i == 1 then ]%%

        <!-- output product 1 here -->

    %%[ elseif @i == 2 then ]%%

        <!-- output product 2 here -->

    %%[ elseif @i == 3 then ]%%

        <!-- output product 3 here -->

    %%[ else ]%%

        <!-- output product default here -->

    %%[ endif ]%%


    %%[ /* if it isn't the last product */ ]%%

    %%[ if @i < @max then ]%%

        <!-- output separator --> 

    %%[ endif ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%
```